# How do you create custom column heading when you do grouping in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a datagrid which is grouped on a column. It does grouping properly but it shows column name + column value. But I want to show only the column value but not the column name. I remember reading there is a method I can overwrite which will allow me to create custom column headers. Could someone point me to the link?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I use thrid party control, it has group header formatter.